# NuGet fails to find existing package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

How it's possible that NuGet's `Install-Package` fails with `Unable to find version 'x' of package 'y'` when that exact version is released as NuGet to the official repository and it shown on the https://www.nuget.org/packages/y page.

Here is specific sample with nuget.org content and NuGet `Install-Package` command output.

[image: nuget package snapshot]

[image: install package failure]

**UPDATE.** Package sources are set to defaults (from nuget.org). Actually, you can see the issue just by running `Install-Package Log4Net.Async -Version 1.3.0`.

[image: package sources]

**UPDATE 2.** I want to highlight that it's not about some developer's machine - the same things happen on Visual Studio Online Hosted Build Controller.

**UPDATE 3.** Here is how NuGet tries to load package and it looks like NuGet API just broken, because all these requests fail with the error below.

[image: install-package intercepted http requests]

> Resource not found for the segment 'Packages'

Also NuGet produces a strange output on NuGet API calls that issued at VS search packages stage, please see here: http://pastebin.com/qveadrZB.

Comment: What are your package sources set to? You may not be searching the online nuget repo

Comment: @bwest, it actually uses defaults that points to nuget.org. I've added this into the description. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: How did you solved? I'm using vs 13

Comment: @RGarcia, as accepted solution states, for me it was just a bad luck of working while nuget.org APIs were not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NuGet currently has some [service issues](http://status.nuget.org) related to search and package restore functionality. It is possible this is the cause of your package restore failure.

If other dev machines are working OK, it's likely they have access to a cached version of this package.

[image: Screenshot of status.nuget.org on 26 May]

Comment: oh, looks exactly like NuGet API failure (see update 3). thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Clear your NuGet cache under options -> NuGet Package Manager

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is very old, but someone who has this problem like me in these days, find my solution for solving such problem here.

I've installed Visual Studio 2012/2015/2017 parallel, and 2012 failed with "package not found error".
So I take a look in the NuGet-settings in VS2017 and found the following package resource:

> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

I just added this location to the package resources and vòila, the searched packages where found and installed (in my example the [HtmlRenderer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.WinForms/1.5.0.6)).

But be careful with compatibility to Framework 2.0! This setting breaks maybe the functionality to version 2.0!!

Hope this helps someone sometimes somewhere.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I'm a latecomer to this thread... I'm in Visual Studio 2017 - 15.9.4

I got this error today trying to pull from my private DevOps NuGet feed

> CONTEXT: 
>   the first time I called `Install-Package` everything worked, but, my NuGet was not assembled right, so, I re-published the NuGet pkg, and
>   when I tried to update my project that was consuming the pkg, that's
>   when I got the failure)

Switching my Package Source to "all" alleviated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on references in your project
2. Manage NuGet Packages => All
3. Uninstall affected packages

If this does not resolve the issue, try to remove it from the NuGet config file located at

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.config
```

Comment: The same issue occurs even with new entirely empty project and on the different machine. Please see the updates.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours struggle I found solution here
https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/docs/uwp/online-getting-started/config-nugetpackage.html

Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources. > Click add button and add following one by one
nuget.org
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

GrapeCity
http://nuget.grapecity.com/nuget
[NuGet settings in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF5ZM.png)