# NuGet fails to find package if it's not in Cache

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, nuget

I have an internal feed setup for NuGet.  When I try to build one of my projects (via a TFS build server), I get an error that NuGet cannot find version xxx of package yyy.

I go to the NuGet package folder on the server and the correct package/version is there.  However, the package/version does not exist in the NuGet cache folder:

C:\Users[user account]\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache

If I copy the correct package/version to this cache folder, then the build succeeds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate with [NuGet fails to find existing package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464558/nuget-fails-to-find-existing-package) . If there are some service issues related to search and package restore functionality. It is possible cause of your package restore failure.

If there is a cached version of this package, NuGet will access there and the restore will be working fine.

The solution is updating your nugget to the latest version (At least 3.4+) You can also refer a similar issue in GitHub: [Package restore intermittently fails with "Unable to find version 'x' of package 'y'"](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1448)

Answer (score -1):

Check Nuget.config in your Project. It should have the path to the Source that is your NuGet package folder on the server should be present in the nuget.config file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageRestore>
    <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />

    <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>

  <activePackageSource>
    <!-- this tells that all of them are active -->
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>

  <packageSources>

    <add key="PrivatePackages" value="\\TestPath\nuget" />

  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```